# How to understand "synthetic" bean archive in weld?

Tags: java, cdi, weld

I am learning [weld](http://www.github.com/weld/core.git). 
And when I study the source code of `org.jboss.weld.environment.se.Weld class` it mention **synthetic bean  archive** several times in *comment*. It seemed it have thing with *beans.xml*.

I guess it is used to tell container load beans specified by manually and at this case we dont need *beans.xml*, **but** that is only my conjecture 
then who can tell me how to understand *synthetic bean archive*?

everything will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Synthetic bean archives are being formalized in CDI 2.0, though impls may use the notion now in a non-portable way.  Docs are in the [CDI 2.0-EDR2](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/2.0.EDR2/cdi-spec.html#se_container_initializer)

Basically, the synthetic bean archive represents the subset of beans that have been loaded while initializing the CDI container.  Assuming you have enabled discovery and just use `initialize()` from Weld, the synthetic bean archive contains the superset of all JAR files on the classpath, using standard bean discovery rules - except that archives without `beans.xml` are excluded.

If you disable discovery and programmatically add beans, the synthetic bean archive represents only those beans that you programmatically added.